# Loading screen for TTImageView

Tags: iphone, three20

I have a table with images that are loaded from the web. I'd like to have an animated loading screen while it's loading.

I tried (successfully) to use a `UIImageView` and use the animation property. I want the loading animation to be synced however. What would be the cleanest way to do this?

I tried to use `NSTimer`. I would use `NSDate` to get miliseconds = m. Then (m * 500) % 4 to get 4 frames per 2 seconds. I wasn't able to get it to work. I also feel it's a bit messy to have 10 to 20 timers going on at the same time. One thing I was thinking is to have a singleton that has a `NSMutableArray` to which you can add a selector that updates the appropriate image. But it's still quite messy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD):

More info:

http://macindie.com/2011/01/mbprogresshud-when-you-simply-have-to-make-users-wait/